# insert component without calling handlebars helper or a controller with outlet

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I want to insert a component into controller template **without** using the handlebars helper (`component "component-name"...` or `component-name`). Or through a controller in an outlet (or as long as the solution works for a component that wants to insert another component, then it's fine, I don't think outlets work in components).

In other words:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
     insertComponent: function() {
       var component = this.container.lookup("component:my-inserted", { singleton: false });
       component.set("layoutName", "components/my-inserted");

       // to be like handlebars-inserted component, what do i do here?
     }
  }
});
```

You can use test with this: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/popozanare/4/edit?html,js,output

Why?

Thinking of a way of to have clean modal syntax, such as the "openModal" syntax described in the Ember Cookbook: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/.

The problem is that the source context is lost, as the modal is within the `ApplicationRoute`. I want the same syntax when calling a modal, but keeping the hierarchy. You can keep the hierarchy using https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog, which requires a mapping of variables... which i don't like either (but will likely implement if I have no other choice).

TD;LR: Want to open modal **within the controller/component (context) that called it** without scaffolding in the controller/component that called it (mapping variables, etc).

Edit:

On second thought, using a container view might be cleaner than mapping variables, found in this solution: http://jsbin.com/hahohi/1/edit?html,js,output. Still needs scaffolding though. Thanks @user3568719.

Comment: Could you give us a use case? Maybe there is a workaround. You can do component. create(). But u have to have a ContaierView to insert it into it. Take a look at this model service, maybe it gives you some idea: http://jsbin.com/hahohi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Kitler edited issue to state why (you might not like why...)

Comment: @user3568719, funny, you kind of guessed the use case. don't think container view will do it....

Answer (score 1):

That cookbook is a bit outdated, but if you are looking for a "clean" way to handling modals in your app I would suggest named outlets.

Add it to your application or auth template `{{outlet "modal"}}` and when you want to bring up the modal you can catch the action on the corresponding route and then render into that named outlet like so:

```
this.render('your-desired-modal-template', {
  into: 'auth',
  outlet: 'modal'
});
```

And when you want to dismiss it simply [disconnectOutlet](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_disconnectOutlet) like so:

```
this.disconnectOutlet({
  outlet: 'modal',
  parentView: 'auth'
});
```

This is the way we've been going about it, I m open to suggestions/better methods.

Comment: what's the key difference between this and the cookbook? the source context still changes to `ApplicationRoute` correct?

the problem i'm having with this approach is a component opening a modal. if i want to access the component that called it.... i can't. thanks for your time :)

Comment: @s12chung The context will change to whatever route called it, that is why I said corresponding route and not the application route. Ran into the context problem and the fastest/sanest way was to call `this.render` from the route that needed it.

Comment: ah... i see. definitely a little better than our current implementation now :)

Comment: Not exactly dry but could probably be refactored into a mixin.

Comment: so... if i mix it in a component, will it work? and will i be able to access the component that called it?

Comment: It seems you have some design issues when it comes to components, your components should send the actions up and have the route handle them, they are meant to remain unaware of their surroundings. And You can't call [.render](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render) on a component it is a route method.

What I am trying to understand is why would you need to access the component that triggered the `openModal` action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81422/discussion-between-kitler-and-s12chung).